# How can I specify an /EXCLUDE file with spaces in it to xcopy?

Tags: windows, command-line, filenames, xcopy, whitespace

I have tried to specify an `/EXCLUDE` filename with spaces in it to `xcopy`, but it always chokes. How can I specify such a path to `xcopy` without copying the `/EXCLUDE` files into the current directory and without using the old DOS `~1` shortname hack?

```
c:\Users\binki\Documents\repos\xcopy_exclude_spacey>dir source
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 7C4E-86D4

 Directory of c:\Users\binki\Documents\repos\xcopy_exclude_spacey\source

2013-01-03  16:39    <DIR>          .
2013-01-03  16:39    <DIR>          ..
2013-01-03  16:39                 0 a
2013-01-03  16:39                 0 a b c
2013-01-03  16:39                 0 b
2013-01-03  16:39                 0 c
               4 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  117,279,027,200 bytes free

c:\Users\binki\Documents\repos\xcopy_exclude_spacey>type "various exclude rules\a"
a

c:\Users\binki\Documents\repos\xcopy_exclude_spacey>xcopy /E /EXCLUDE:"various exclude rules\a" source dest
Can't read file: "various exclude rules\a"

0 File(s) copied

c:\Users\binki\Documents\repos\xcopy_exclude_spacey>xcopy /E "/EXCLUDE:various exclude rules\a" source dest
Invalid number of parameters
```

None of the ways of quoting the filename which would work fine in a decent shell work for me with xcopy. For some reason, `"/EXCLUDE:<filename>"` syntax prevents the option itself from being recognized. The other syntax, `"/EXCLUDE:"<filename>"`, causes the message `Can't read file: "<filename>"` to be printed, showing that the option is being parsed correctly: the double-quotes are preventing the argument from being split up into multiple parts. However, this message suggests that the double-quotes are not being properly stripped from the filename by xcopy before it tries to open the file.

It seems, from this, that if the first component of the path I specify in `/EXCLUDE` started with a `"` and my `/EXCLUDE` filename ends in `"`, I would be able to reference that file from xcopy’s `/EXCLUDE` option successfully. But Windows refuses to let me place the `"` character in my filename.

So, how do I use xcopy in a modern world with spacey filenames?

Comment: xcopy is a pretty old program.  Easy suggestion, stop using filenames with spaces....they are a pain to deal with generally in all OSen as they tend to be argument seperators.

Comment: All OSes other than Windows seem to use something like a POSIX shell and environment which has a well-enough-defined method for specifying file paths with spaces. Windows apparently doesn’t have a way to truly pass multiple arguments to a launched program but passes the arguments as a flat string, meaning argument delimitation happens at the wrong time. But Windows is the OS where spaces in path names are most common, so there must be a solution to this problem, especially since the xcopy in Windows 8 cannot be the same xcopy in Windows 98.

Comment: I suppose, however, that [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) probably works in this situation and is available as long as you’re targetting a modern Windows.